# How do I say: "I didn’t call because I had a cold"

Tags: grammar

If you wanted to say that you didn’t call someone because you had a cold, do you say: 風邪をひいてたから電話しませんでした or do you say: 風邪をひいたから電話しませんでした (or maybe even 風邪をひいてたから電話してませんでした?)
This whole ています／てます thing is really confusing to me.

Answer (score 3):

I think

- 風邪をひい**て(い)た**から電話**し**ませんでした

is most natural while

- 風邪をひい**た**から電話しませんでした

is ok.

On the other hand 電話し**て(い)**ませんでした is usually odd.

テイル形 has various meanings and I suppose you can check your textbook ([This](http://www.wayaku.jp/blog/?p=758) may give the idea of its variety). Which meaning is the default varies from verb to verb.

Without context,

- 電話している means progressive 'is calling', so 電話してませんでした would mean 'wasn't calling', which wouldn't fit in the sentence in question.
- 風邪をひいている does not mean progressive (in the process of getting cold), but simply indicate the subject is in state of having a cold. 風邪をひいた means a simple past, which works ok in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

「風邪をひいていて電話しませんでした」or「風邪をひいて電話しませんでした」is natural. 風邪をひいていて is not past expression but in Japanese language, past expression is not needed because 電話した is past.